# How do i change the date format to (YYYY-YY) in the bar chart

Tags: python

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Data for reference and how i want the date format to look like:

[image]

```
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter
def formatter(x, pos):
    return str(round(x / 1e6, 1)) + " million"
df = pd.DataFrame(df_student_enrollment)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 2e7])
plt.bar(X, Y, color='b')
plt.title("Student Enrollment")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Number of students(in millions)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: No the format is YYYY-YY, as in timeframe from lets say, 2019-20